# Pandas dataframe from non scalar values and nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Currently, I get have a dictionary with scalar values and a nested dictionary.

```
d = {'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C':{0:'z', 1:'y'}}
```

I would like to put this into a pandas dataframe. However,

```
pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0])
```

Gives me only the first value of the nested dictionary. That is,
[image].

Any idea how I can get
[image]
instead?

Is there an elegant solution available? I'm hoping to avoid writing any loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put dict to list like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([d])
print(df)
   A  B                 C
0  a  b  {0: 'z', 1: 'y'}
```